# What is the adjoint operator for the Diag function?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, inner-products, adjoint-operators, positive-semidefinite

The Diag function sends a vector x in R^n to the diagonal nxn matrix with the components of x along the diagonal. The Diag function is a linear map from R^n to S^n_+, the set of symmetric positive semidefinite matrices.

Since it is a linear map between two inner product spaces, a natural question would be to ask: what is the adjoint operator of the Diag function? I guess that it is the diag function, which takes a matrix and outputs the vector of diagonal entries. Is that true?

The adjoint of a linear map $\mathcal A$ between two inner product spaces $X$ and $Y$ is another linear map denoted $\mathcal A^*$, satisfying $$\langle \mathcal A(x),y\rangle = \langle x, \mathcal A^*(y) \rangle ,$$
for any $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$.

Comment: Yes, it is true. Use the definition of adjoint to check that it is true (the definition with inner products).

Comment: What do you mean by the adjoint of a linear map between two different inner product spaces?